# Products Detail on Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app

I've just started using SF1 and I've encountered a problem.

I need to get to the detail page of the Product Standard Object on SF1. I've tried using `sforce.one.navigateToSObject(recordId)` but I get this message: *'The page you are trying to access is not supported on mobile devices.'* . I have been able to access other objects this way, but not Products.

I've created a custom visualforce page, used the apex:Detail tag on it and I get to this page using `sforce.one.navigateToURL('url')` , but the layout is the standard salesforce layout with standard salesforce styles.

Is there a way to see the Product Object detail on SF1 with SF1 styles?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you will need to wait until the Spring 14 release to be able to see products in Salesforce1. Sign up for a pre-release org and you'll see that there are compact layouts available for products.

You can find the link to sign up for a prerelease org as well as dates for the release here: http://blogs.salesforce.com/company/2013/12/salesforce-spring-14-release-dates.html